# Mix colors from different objects at collision (Rigid Bodies and Particles)

Tags: particles, rigid-body-simulation, color

This will be a pretty complex question, many areas will be connected to it but it is for sure focused on one main problem. I'm not sure is it possible without heavy scripting and I didn't found anything on this topic elsewhere. So off we go.

### Abstract:

I want to mix colors from different objects on collision.

**Example.** One cube is blue, second is yellow. Boom! Both are green.

I've made this little simulation:

[image: Cubes]

### Going deeper:

I think that the best option would be making material with *RGB* node, then, after taking color from another object mix them with *MixRGB* as below:

[image: Color_mix]

As you can see first problem is that Blender isn't mixing colors as it should, but let say it's close enough and leave it for now as is.

Second one is scenario with many objects. Using same approach will give us enormous amount of nodes - by adding another Mix and RGB. Replacing one color on the other hand doesn't give us proper mixing.

Solution for second problem could be making one RGB node from mixed values and waiting for another hit.

### Wrap this up:

If there is any logic behind it, it could probably works like that:

1. Get RGB values of both objects.
2. Detect collision.
3. Mix values and replace existing RGB node value with new one.
4. Wait for another hit.

### Advanced usage:

You may ask: "What you want to do with this dummy?" and my answer is:

[image: spheres]

[Molecular Script](http://pyroevil.com/molecular-script-docs/) from Pyroevil.

In this script there is collision system so (as far as I know about Python scripting like Jon Snow) it will be matter of adding color change thingy to this. Or I'm just delusional.

It will be great thing to mix particle collision systems colors. It could open new way to simulate fluids. If it's possible to transfer particle color values to IsoSurface in CubeSurfer or any other mesher possibilities will be endless (nooo, it's just for pouring blood to milk).

### Blend file:

Here is my blend file if somebody wants to play with it (Molecular Script needed).

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Using Animation Nodes

<sup>Updated for Animation Nodes 2.0!</sup>

***Method with the* [Molecular Modifier](http://pyroevil.com/molecular-script-download/) *and* [CubeSurfer](http://pyroevil.com/cubesurfer-addon-download/) *below!!!***

Another way to do this is using [@Jacques Lucke](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/5449/jacques-lucke)'s **[Animation Nodes](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes)** addon. Here is the final result:

[image]

And here is a picture of the node setup:

[image]

This is done with a *Rigid Body Simulation* and *Vertex Colors*. After installing **Animation Nodes** (linked above), we can get to work.

### 1. Setting Up the Scene

First, we have to set up our *Rigid Bodies*. Add a ground plane, and under the *Physics* tab of the **Properties Editor**, click on *Rigid Body* and uncheck *Active*. For every object that we want to actively collide, click on *Rigid Body*, but leave *Active* checked.

[image]

In addition, under the *Mesh* tab of the **Properties Editor**, add a vertex color by clicking the <kbd>+</kbd> button under the *Vertex Colors* panel. Since we have to do this for every object, we can save ourselves some typing by leaving the default name, `Col`.

[image]

The last thing we have is give it a material. Call it whatever you want, and then create the following (Cycles) NodeTree:

[image]

This can be modified as needed, as long as the vertex color is still a part of the nodetree.

Repeat the above for all of the objects you want to mix color, giving the *the same* material, or just duplicate the one object. Finally, select all of the objects you want to mix colors and group them together (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>). Don't forget to name it, either in the <kbd>T</kbd> panel or by hitting <kbd>F6</kbd>.

[image]

The scene is set up now. Let's dive into the Animation Nodes!

### 2. Creating the Nodetree

In the node window, click on the Animation Nodes. Add an *Objects From Group* node (to add a node, either press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and find the node, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to search for it). Select the Group.

[image]

The first thing we want to do is to assign random colors to each object on Frame 1. Let's create a subprogram to do that. Add a *Loop Input* node and name it `SetRandCol`. Press the <kbd>+</kbd> button next to *New Iterator* and type "Object List". Set up the following nodes:

[image]

To activate the loop, add an *Invoke Subprogram* node, select `SetRandCol`, and plug in the Object list. It should take effect immediately.

[image]

We don't want this to happen every frame, though. Just the first. Add these nodes to make it only work on Frame 1:

[image]

Cool. The next step is to calculate all of the different pairs of objects we will have to check collision against. We could do this with nodes, but it is faster to just use a short script. First, add a *Get List Length* node and plug in the Object list. Next, add a *Script* node and name it `FindPairs`. Press the <kbd>+</kbd> button to add a new script. Use the buttons to add 1 input (an integer) and 2 outputs (integer lists). Name them as follows:

[image]

In a **Text Editor** window, open the `FindPairs` script and paste the following:

```python
obj1, obj2 = [],[]

for i in range(0,objcount):
    for j in range(i,objcount):
        if i != j:
            obj1.append(i)
            obj2.append(j)
```

To use the script, add an *Invoke Subprogram* node and select the "FindPairs" option. Plug the *Get List Length* node into the script node. `obj1` and `obj2` are all the pairs of objects (i.e. index `0` goes with index `0`, etc).

[image]

The next thing to do is to create a loop that checks every pair for collision. We will do this with the *Is Inside Volume* node. Create a loop the same way we did the first time. Name it `BVHCollide`. Give it two "Integer List" iterators (named `obj1` and `obj2`), an "Object List" parameter, and a "Float" parameter named `Epsilon`.

[image]

Add these nodes:

[image]

Next, we need to check for collision between the two objects. We'll use the *Is Inside Volume* node. After we check for collision, we'll combine our data to get a single boolean value for whether or not the two objects intersect:

[image]

The `Epsilon` parameter determines how far outside the loop the BVH node will look. Usually a super-low, non-zero value will work, like `0.0002`. The last thing to do is to change the color of the objects. Add one more loop:

[image]

In the *Advanced Node Settings* dropdown of the <kbd>N</kbd> panel for the *Expression* nodes, be sure to uncheck "Correct Type":

[image]

Finally, invoke this last loop, and your simulation should work!

[image]

---

**Blend File** (requires Animation Nodes):

[image]

---

If you want to set the color manually, you can create this loop. Just provide it a list of colors with corresponding indices to the list of objects:

[image]

---

## Incorporating the [Molecular Modifier](http://pyroevil.com/molecular-script-download/)

Incorporating the Molecular Modifier has a similar workflow to the Rigid Body Method. Begin by setting up a Molecular simulation. Here is mine:

[image]

Here is the final result:

[image]

Node setup:

[image]

After setting up the molecular simulation, we can work on the coloring. To color the particles, we are exploiting a feature of the Molecular Modifier: since the entire simulation is baked with its own physics, the particles never rotate and therefore never use the *Angular Velocity* attribute. We will store our colors there. Set all of the particles to render as an *Icosphere* object and give the Icosphere this material:

[image]

Now lets get into **Animation Nodes**. Unfortunately, in Animation Nodes 2.0, the *Particle* datatype has been removed. The most efficient way to get around this is to create our own in Python. First, let's create an **Extract Particles** node. Add a **Script** node, and give it *Particle System* input and a *Generic List* output. Name the List `ParticleList`. Create a new script file and paste in this code:

```python
ParticleList = []

for p in ParticleSystem.particles:
    ParticleList.append(p)
```

[image]

Next, we need a **Filter Particles** node. Add another **Script** node, and give it a *Generic List* input, four *Boolean* inputs, and a *Generic List* output. Name them as follows:

[image]

Here is the script:

```python
Filtered = []

for p in Particles:
    if Unborn:
        if p.alive_state == 'UNBORN':
            Filtered.append(p)
    if Alive:
        if p.alive_state == 'ALIVE':
            Filtered.append(p)
    if Dying:
        if p.alive_state == 'DYING':
            Filtered.append(p)
    if Dead:
        if p.alive_state == 'DEAD':
            Filtered.append(p)
```

Last, we need a **Particle Data** node, to get information from the particles. Add another **Script** node, and give it a *Generic List* input, a *Vector List* output, a *Float List* output, and a *Color List* output. Name them as follows:

[image]

Here is the script:

```python
Locations, Sizes, AngularVelocities = [],[],[]

for p in ParticleList:
    Locations.append(p.location)
    Sizes.append(p.size)
    AngularVelocities.append(p.angular_velocity)
```

For some reason, Animation Nodes doesn't like us using a Color List to store vector data, so disable *Correct Output Types* in the **Advanced Node Settings** panel of the <kbd>N</kbd> sidebar for the *Script Node*:

[image]

Now that we have that set up, we can get on to coloring the particles. For each of our particle emitters, add a **Particle Systems from Object** node. Add one of our **ExtractParticles** nodes for each Particle System:

[image]

We need a way to color the particles. Create a new **Script** subprogram named **Color Particles**. Give it two *Color* inputs and one *Generic List* input:

[image]

Code:

```python
for p in particles:
    if color1 != color2:
        p.angular_velocity = [(color1[0]+color2[0])/2,(color1[1]+color2[1])/2,(color1[2]+color2[2])/2]
```

To set the initial colors for each particles system, use a **FilterParticles** node to get unborn particles, then the **Color Particles** node to set the color. Note that the two color inputs have to be different for the node to take effect:

[image]

Now, join all the particles together with a **Combine List** node and use a **FilterParticles** node to get a list of all Alive particles:

[image]

Next, we need to calculate all the different pairs of particles to check collision for. We can just use the same node we created above:

[image]

At this point, the numbers start to get really big, and unless you have an über-fast computer, you're going to start to lag. Even then, this NodeTree works better if it's only executed once a frame. If you haven't already, you should turn off *Always* in the **Auto Execution** panel of the <kbd>T</kbd> sidebar:

[image]

Ok. Next, let's check collision. Since everything is a perfect sphere, the math is pretty simple. The **Loop** node will need 2 *Integer List* iterators (`obj1` and `obj2`), a *Vector List* parameter, a *Float List* parameter, a *Float* parameter, and a *Boolean List* output. Here is the NodeTree:

[image]

We can invoke it like so:

[image]

We now have a problem. We have an enormous amount of data. For my little 8000 particle simulation, there are over *2 million* particle pairs that have to be checked for collision. If we also have to check if they need to have their colors modified, it would take ***forever***. So, we should optimize the lists to only have pairs for which collision is true. Create a **Script** node with an  *Integer List* and a *Boolean List* input and an *Integer List* output:

[image]

Here is the script:

```python
n = [i[a] for a in range(len(i)) if b[a]]
```

Use this **Prune** node on both of the `obj` lists:

[image]

Lastly, we need to change the color of all the colliding pairs. Since we already have a script to calculate and change the color of a pair of particles, we don't have to do much. Create this **Loop**:

[image]

Make sure to change the *Slice Type* from *Index* to *Length*. To finish, put in the **Update Particles** node:

[image]

***Done!!!***

#### Notes:

This will *not* run in real-time. For an 8000 particle simulation, it takes my (about average) computer 6-7 seconds to calculate each frame. Realize that the number of pairs increases quadratically, not linearly, so a 10000 particle simulation will take roughly four times as long as a 5000 particle simulation, depending on how many collisions there are.

Be sure to save before rendering. With both the Molecular script and Animation Nodes running, my computer froze once while rendering (I only have 8GB of RAM, though).

[image]

---

**Blend File** (requires Animation Nodes and Molecular):

[image]

---

## Using [CubeSurfer](http://pyroevil.com/cubesurfer-addon-download/)

We can even mesh our simulation and transfer the colors from the particles to the mesh. I'm using [CubeSurfer](http://pyroevil.com/cubesurfer-addon-download/) to mesh my particles. It's pretty easy to pick up (controls are at the bottom of the **Object** panel) and there are tutorials online. Doing this will slow down the simulation a little more, but the NodeTree is pretty simple:

[image]

The two Reroutes are bringing in the list of active particles, and the locations of those particles, as labeled, from their respective nodes in the Main frame of the previous NodeTree. The object in the **Object Input** node is the `Isosurface` object created by **CubeSurfer**. You'll need to enable visibility for the *Polygon Centers* output of the **Object Mesh Data** node in the <kbd>N</kbd> panel. Here is the `SetVertexCol` script:

```python
Object.data.vertex_colors.new() #Add a new vertex color, since it gets deleted at every frame change.
v_colors = Object.data.vertex_colors["Col"].data #Get the vertex color data
colors = [ParticleList[i].angular_velocity for i in Indices] #Get the colors for each face from the particles
i,j = 0,0
for f in Object.data.polygons:        #Iterate through each face
    for l in f.loop_indices:          #Iterate through each vertex
        v_colors[i].color = colors[j] #Paint vertex with color
        i += 1                        #Increment vertex
    j += 1                            #Increment face
```

The above code works because Vertex Color data is stored as a list of colors sorted by face, then vertex, which happens to be in the same order the Animation Nodes gets the faces.

Final Result:

[image]

It looks pretty awesome. Unfortunately, converting it to `.gif` form took down the quality. You can watch the full clip on YouTube [here](https://youtu.be/kVTJi5s5nYM). I recommend watching in slow motion so you can see it frame by frame.

---

**Blend File** (Requires Animation Nodes, Molecular, and CubeSurfer):

[image]

Comment: Amazing, I can't wait! Thanks in advance. I'm learning AN now hard as hell, it's a pitty that there are so little resources about them.

Comment: @LukeD Agreed. There are several YouTube videos with a lot of examples you can find, along with some BlenderArtists threads.

Comment: @LukeD Updated for Animation Nodes 2.0.

Comment: @JacquesLucke Where did the Particle datatype go?

Comment: @LukeD And I finally got it working with CubeSurfer.

Comment: I'm really astonished with this method. I think it's first documented way to make fluid mixing in Blender. You should really think about making a comprehensive tutorial about it on YT. The one thing just bothers me. Why colors are "washed out" without CubeSurfer? I've tried to mix yellow with blue but it just gives me light blue color. Even if yellow particles are in 3:1 ratio. Script for Additive Color Mixing is fine, so what could be the problem?

Comment: @LukeD I'm not sure I understand your issue, but could it be that did some color correction on the IsoSurface material to make the colors brighter? The actual vertex color is a lot lighter.

Comment: @ScottMilner: WOW!!!! One of the best answers i ever saw here on Blender stack exchange!

Answer (score 12):

Light code gets promising results already.
I made an example with rigid body meshes instead of particles. Spherical particle will be easy to detect as well since a collision is defined by their distance.

A rigid body simulation.

[image]

The simulation after executing the script.

[image]

The code.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils.bvhtree import BVHTree
import mathutils

def fat_bm(scn, obj, fatten = 0.1, remove = True):
    dp = obj.modifiers.get("intersect_disp")
    if (dp == None):
        dp = obj.modifiers.new('intersect_disp','DISPLACE')
    dp.strength = fatten;
    me = obj.to_mesh(scn, True, 'PREVIEW')
    if (remove):
        obj.modifiers.remove(dp)
    
    for v in me.vertices:
        v.co = obj.matrix_world * v.co
    bm = bmesh.new() 
    bm.from_mesh(me)
    return bm

def get_overlaps(scn, obj1, obj2, fatten = 0.1, remove = True):
    
    bm_a = fat_bm(scn, obj1, fatten, remove)
    bm_b = fat_bm(scn, obj2, fatten, remove)

    tree_a = BVHTree.FromBMesh(bm_a)
    tree_b = BVHTree.FromBMesh(bm_b)

    bm_a.free()
    bm_b.free()

    overlap_pairs = tree_b.overlap(tree_a)
    return overlap_pairs

def converge_dif_color(obj1, obj2, fac = 1.0):
    a = obj1.data.materials[0].diffuse_color
    b = obj2.data.materials[0].diffuse_color
    c = mathutils.Color((0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
    sat = (a.s + b.s)/2
    val = (a.v + b.v)/2
    hue_dif = b.h - a.h
    hue = a.h + hue_dif/2
    if (hue_dif > 0.5):
        hue = b.h - ((b.h-(1+a.h))/2)
    if (hue_dif < -0.5):
        hue = a.h + (((b.h + 1)-a.h)/2)
    while (hue >= 1):
        hue -=1
    c.hsv = hue, sat, val
    
    obj1.data.materials[0].diffuse_color = (a * (1-fac) + c * fac)
    obj2.data.materials[0].diffuse_color = (b * (1-fac) + c * fac)
    
def compute_material_color(scene, objs, distance = 0.1, color_mix_per_frame = 1.0):
    # TODO check if objs have single user materials
    
    # TODO delete ONLY color keyframes
    
    
    for f in range(scene.frame_start, scene.frame_end + 1):
        print(f)
        scene.frame_set(f)
        
        for i, ob1 in enumerate(objs):
            ob2 = None
            if (i == 0):
                ob2 = objs[len(objs)-1]
            else:
                ob2 = objs[i -1]
            #print(ob1.name, ob2.name)
            if (len(get_overlaps(scene, ob1, ob2, distance)) > 0):
                converge_dif_color(ob1, ob2, color_mix_per_frame)
                
            for ob in objs:
                ob.data.materials[0].keyframe_insert(data_path="diffuse_color")


scene = bpy.context.scene
sel = []
for ob in scene.objects:
    if (ob.select == True):
        sel.append(ob)

compute_material_color(scene, sel, 0.3, 0.4)
```

To use this code, create some colliding objects, assign them unique color with different materials. Use only few objects at first, the script still has some problems. Select the objects and run the script.

### Walkthrough

```
import bmesh
from mathutils.bvhtree import BVHTree
import mathutils
```

The **bvhtree** module in combination with an input bmesh is used to detect intersections.

```
def fat_bm(scn, obj, fatten = 0.1, remove = True):
    dp = obj.modifiers.get("intersect_disp")
    if (dp == None):
        dp = obj.modifiers.new('intersect_disp','DISPLACE')
    dp.strength = fatten;
    me = obj.to_mesh(scn, True, 'PREVIEW')
    if (remove):
        obj.modifiers.remove(dp)
    
    for v in me.vertices:
        v.co = obj.matrix_world * v.co
    bm = bmesh.new() 
    bm.from_mesh(me)
    return bm
```

We can't detect collisions, but we can detect intersection. Lets blow up the object in question with a displacement modifier, making it fatter. Two close by object would therefore intersect. Get a mesh with modifier applied, delete the modifier and return a bmesh.

```
def get_overlaps(scn, obj1, obj2, fatten = 0.1, remove = True):
    
    bm_a = fat_bm(scn, obj1, fatten, remove)
    bm_b = fat_bm(scn, obj2, fatten, remove)

    tree_a = BVHTree.FromBMesh(bm_a)
    tree_b = BVHTree.FromBMesh(bm_b)

    bm_a.free()
    bm_b.free()

    overlap_pairs = tree_b.overlap(tree_a)
    return overlap_pairs
```

Using the fattened bmesh objects, check if two objects intersect using the bvhtree overlap function. Return the number of overlaps.

```
def converge_dif_color(obj1, obj2, fac = 1.0):
    a = obj1.data.materials[0].diffuse_color
    b = obj2.data.materials[0].diffuse_color
    c = mathutils.Color((0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
    sat = (a.s + b.s)/2
    val = (a.v + b.v)/2
    hue_dif = b.h - a.h
    hue = a.h + hue_dif/2
    if (hue_dif > 0.5):
        hue = b.h - ((b.h-(1+a.h))/2)
    if (hue_dif < -0.5):
        hue = a.h + (((b.h + 1)-a.h)/2)
    while (hue >= 1):
        hue -=1
    c.hsv = hue, sat, val
    
    obj1.data.materials[0].diffuse_color = (a * (1-fac) + c * fac)
    obj2.data.materials[0].diffuse_color = (b * (1-fac) + c * fac)
```

A very unfinished function of combining two colors. If you would add up each channel and do something like this `(r1 + r2) / 2`  everything will turn gray. I tried to find the closest connection in the hue circle. A factor is used so that color may change more slowly over more frames.

```
def compute_material_color(scene, objs, distance = 0.1, color_mix_per_frame = 1.0):
    # TODO check if objs have single user materials
    
    # TODO delete ONLY color keyframes
    
    
    for f in range(scene.frame_start, scene.frame_end + 1):
        print(f)
        scene.frame_set(f)
        
        for i, ob1 in enumerate(objs):
            ob2 = None
            if (i == 0):
                ob2 = objs[len(objs)-1]
            else:
                ob2 = objs[i -1]
            #print(ob1.name, ob2.name)
            if (len(get_overlaps(scene, ob1, ob2, distance)) > 0):
                converge_dif_color(ob1, ob2, color_mix_per_frame)
                
            for ob in objs:
                ob.data.materials[0].keyframe_insert(data_path="diffuse_color")
```

Cycle through all frames. On each frame, cycles through all objects and check if a pair has more than 0 intersections. If yes, converge their colors.

#### To do

- clean up meshes which gets created with applied modifiers
- (OR) get a more efficient method to detect collisions
- converge the hsv colors more naturally
- check if there are keyframes on the color channels, if yes, remove them first
- adjust the keyframing for the specific setup (e.g. cycles diffuse nodes)
- add **iterations** to the color calculation, right now we're only checking on each objects once one after the other, this produces inaccurate results when an object *collides* with more than one other

Useful snippets for testing.

### Assign random colors

```
import bpy
import random

objs = bpy.context.selected_objects

for ob in objs:
    r, g, b = [random.random() for i in range(3)]
    ob.data.materials[0].diffuse_color = (r, g, b)
```

### Delete all keyframes from the diffuse channels

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
objs = bpy.context.selected_objects

for f in range(scene.frame_start, scene.frame_end + 1):
    for ob in objs:
        ob.data.materials[0].keyframe_delete(data_path="diffuse_color", index = -1, frame = f)
```

The required `distance` and `mix amount` get passed through all functions.

```
compute_material_color(scene, objs, distance, color_mix_per_frame)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution might be using UPBGE:

Use this node setup:

[image]

and you get:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

And what about changing the particles color of your two particles systems as soon as they are : 
 - below a given z value ; 
 - or inside a given coordinates system ?

I'm an artist, so I have no any idea of how to do this, and if such thing is only possible, but if this can help you even a little.

Comment: It's not helpful at all, if you pour both particle system to the ground first and then wait them to meet in the middle. Second thing, what if particle system is set to have random colors? And lastly, when you set uneven particle distribution color mixing will be completely different.

Comment: for an artist is not such a bad answer, at least he be right in the sense that visually it would look smooth, btw eaasy to also by particle age. so kudos