# How to make an object change its color when it collides with another?

Tags: objects, color, collision

I think the title explains it well. I want to make two objects collide and change the color of one of them. How can I do this using physics, in cycles?

Thanks.

Comment: In cycles? Using physics? please be more specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mix colors from different objects at collision (Rigid Bodies and Particles)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71851/mix-colors-from-different-objects-at-collision-rigid-bodies-and-particles)

Comment: Yes, using Cycles and physics.

Comment: I've seen that thread Duarte, but what happens is that the colors of the objects mix together when they collide and they are also randomly selected. I don't know how to change that node tree so that I can choose the colors myself and make only one object change color on impact (not adquiring the color of the other object).