# Is There An Easy Way To Have An Object Make A Sound When It Collides With Something?

Tags: audio, rigidbody

Is there an easy way to have 2 rigid bodies make sounds when they collide with each other.

I can't make a script to do something like that could some one help me.

Comment: Could you share your script as an answer, please?

Comment: I haven't created the script yet as I don't do much scripting with blender.

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/79348/30849). There is a "collision detection" in there. I guess the interesting part is the "*get_overlaps*" method.

Comment: Thanks I will start working on the script.

Comment: @Leander the scripts collision detection is quite  good compared to other ones just one question what do I need to put as the thing that that dictates weather to do the action or not.

Comment: Never mind I can't do this.