# How to make an object change color after being touched by another object?

Tags: python, animation, materials

So I've several dominoes in a circle, and I would like each domino to change color after being touched by the previous domino. I can do it manually using keyframes but this will take ages they are 200. So is there is an easier way to do it? Is there is a script that automatically adds a changing color keyframe every 10 frames as that is what I found to be suitable.

Comment: Not really, I think my problem is much more simple, because it is automatic I just want to create color keyframes every 10 frames

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71851