# How to make objects change color depending on color at a point on surface of another object they are closest to?

Tags: shaders, color, vertex-colors

I wanted to try to create a shader which will take the information from a linked object, and based on the closer colour of the surface of that object, it will apply that same colour to the objects that have this material applied to.

Example: let's say I have a model of Superman, then, I want to create a few objects around him.

To these objects I apply this shader, and when doing so, the object that is close to the skin will automatically get the skin colour.
The one close to the cape will get red.
The one close to the arm will be blue.

I don't need it to be completely precise if an object is near the symbol in the chest, I don't need it to take both yellow and red depending on what part of the symbol is near what part of the object, but basically, that would be what I'm trying to accomplish.

Now, I'm fairly new to blender and the whole shaders system so I'm not sure if this is doable and / or how to do it.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71851/mix-colors-from-different-objects-at-collision-rigid-bodies-and-particles/