# Change color of Passive rigid body when collide with active rigid body?

Tags: color

Is there a solution for my issue:

I have 1 active rigid body and 30 passive rigid bodies.
When active rigid body collides with the passive body then I would like to change passive rigid body color at random.

Would this be possible somehow?
I'm newbie in blender but keen to learn!

At the moment I do manually change the color via keyframes and surface emissions, but this is time consuming.

This is not a duplicate or similar to the post : **[thread here!](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71851/mix-colors-from-different-objects-at-collision-rigid-bodies-and-particles)**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Solution for all cases may not be easy. Please provide an example of your scene, type of objects (shapes) and what kind of simulation you are running.

Comment: and you should elaborate why this is NOT a duplicate. The way you write this question is for me a clear duplicate of the link you provide, sorry. Then tell us the difference!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mix colors from different objects at collision (Rigid Bodies and Particles)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71851/mix-colors-from-different-objects-at-collision-rigid-bodies-and-particles)

Comment: Hello, Stag, welcome  .. it would justify your post, and help us aim accurately at the right answer for you, if you explained  **why** your question is not the same as the suggested duplicate.